# Fechas SQL problema formato

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statements

Tengo dos variables de tipo `sql.Date` que quiero almacenar en la base de datos, pero a la hora de insertar en [sqldeveloper](/questions/tagged/sqldeveloper) mediante un `PreparedStatement`, cuando recojo el date con un conversor de `JDateChooser` a `sql.Date`, el valor que recoge la base de datos es totalmente distinto al que elegí en el `JDateChooser`.

[image: Este es el conversor]

Creo el objeto `Programador` con los dos `Date` ya convertidos a `sql.Date` y los inserto en la base de datos con el setDate. El problema está entre el conversor, la forma de recibir la fecha del `JDateChooser` o la forma de mandarlo a la base de datos. Tampoco sé si el formato de fecha de SQL Developer y el de `JDateChooser` pueden rayar el programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdón si me expliqué mal, llevo poco programando y aún no sé manejar bien todo.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: No sabemos qué programa detecta qué dato porque no sabemos cómo estás interpretando el resultado, el tipo de dato que usas, etc. Tampoco sabemos en la base de datos (qué motor será?) qué tipo de dato tiene la columna que usas y cómo la consultas. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: ya probaste que pasa cuando usas Date de java util?

Comment: La razón es simple. El [constructor de Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#constructor.summary) acepta (año, mes, día), en ese orden, y tu lo estás pasando en un orden bien raro (dia, mes, año). Por otro lado tu método `JDateChooseradate` se puede resumir a una línea `return fecha.getDate()`. No necesitas tanto boilerplate que no sirve de nada. Ya `getDate` te devuelve un objeto `Date` con la fecha.

Comment: Por favor, el código va a TEXTO. Es muy importante que recuerdes eso para futuras preguntas (y si puedes, edita esta).

Comment: Por cierto para convertir de `Date` a `sql.Date` basta con `java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());`

Comment: Por favor, deja el código en formato código, no de imagen, parece una tontería, pero no lo es, pues nos permite poder copiarlo y pegarlo de manera rápida para poder proceder a ayudarte diréctamente sin necesidad de escribirlo a mano.